# How to multiply integer with float values in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, multiplication

I am learning Smalltalk a few days ago and, I am working on the project that is basically finding the Area and Perimeter for Circle Class that is implementing from Shape Class. In other words, Shape is a super class for Circle.

When I run my code, I got the error saying, "numeric primitive expected numeric argument, got ".  I believe that the error occurs because I am multiplying integer with float value.  I have no idea how to fix the error, so if someone can please give me some suggestions?

P.S - I am using usmalltalk, which is a specific version of Smalltalk, but it has the same features.

```
(class Shape Object 
   (Perimeter Area)
   (method getPerimeter() Perimeter)

   (method setPerimeter:(Perim)
       (set Perimeter Perim) 
   )


   (method CreateShape::(Perim Ar)
      (set Perimeter Perim)
      (set Area Ar)
      self
   )

   (class-method NewShape:: (Perimeter Area)
        (CreateShape:: (new self) Perimeter Area)
    )
)


(class Circle Shape
   (Radius)

   (method getRadius() Radius)

   (method setRadius:(radi)
       (set Radius radi)
       (set Perimeter (* (* 2 (asFloat (/ 22 7))) Radius)) #The error exits here
       (set Area (* (* (asFloat (/ 22 7)) Radius) Radius))
   )

   (method CreateCircle:(radi)
       (set Radius radi)
       self
   )

   (class-method NewCircle: (Radius)
       (CreateCircle: (new self) Radius)
   )

)
```

Comment: Where does `setRadius` get invoked?

Comment: @ScottHunter , When I call setRadius in the Circle class will update Perimeter and Area (using from Shape) for Circle class using the equation (shown)

Comment: The error message actually implies that you're trying to multiply by an empty string...

Comment: Please show the call to setRadius.

Answer (score 4):

The Smalltalk dialect you are using doesn't follow the conventional Smalltalk syntax, so let me translate the offending expression into the more familiar one.

Let's parse the expression

```
(* (* 2 (asFloat (/ 22 7))) Radius)
```

In what follows, the expression on the right of `-->` is the conventional form of the expression on the left.

Step 1:

```
/ 22 27 --> 22/27
```

Step 2:

```
asFloat(/ 22 7) --> (22/27) asFloat
```

Step 3:

```
* 2 (asFloat (/ 22 27)) --> 2 * (22/27) asFloat
```

Step 4:

```
* (* 2 (asFloat (/ 22 27)) Radius) --> (2 * (22 / 27) asFloat) * Radius
```

Therefore, an error here means that `Radius` is not a number. As suggested in the comments, the problem is that the `Radius` variable has not been assigned a proper (i.e., numeric) value, and this is what the error message is somehow trying to tell.

Of course, the `Radius` variable takes its value from the `radi` argument sent to the `setRadius:` method. This means that the origin of the problem is in the sender of `setRadius:`. But here is where the analysis of the source code gets tricky because it is *static* and it doesn't show the sequence of steps in the execution of your program.

A better approach to understand the problem is a *dynamic* one. In Smalltalk you do that with the help of the debugger. I'm not familiar with the Smalltalk dialect you are using, but when the error pops up, you should be offered some way to debug your code. Accept that option and examine the list of messages that were sent right before the error was signaled. Once you locate the method that evaluates the expression at Step 4, check the value of the `Radius` variable and see what's in there. It shouldn't be a number, otherwise there wouldn't be any error. From there you should be able to trace back to the place where the formal argument `radi` gets its actual value, which leads to the root of the problem.

One final remark. Your question reads **How to multiply integers with floats** in Smalltalk. The answer is **just multiply them using `*`**.  Smalltalk will figure it out how to proceed. You don't need to send any conversion messages such as `asFloat` or the like (you can remove them from your code so to simplify it.) Smalltalk dynamic typing frees the programmer from spending time in type-casting variables. Not because there is any magic in the compiler but because of the polymorphic nature of the language.